# Execute Teradata UDF Triggers Data Type does not match a Defined Type name

Tags: sql, types, teradata, user-defined-functions

I have the following Teradata UDF:

```
REPLACE FUNCTION MIGRATION_TOOL.GET_OBJECT_TYPE(OBJECT_KIND VARCHAR(2))
RETURNS CHARACTER(20)
CONTAINS SQL
SPECIFIC MIGRATION_TOOL.GET_OBJECT_TYPE
COLLATION INVOKER
INLINE TYPE 1
RETURN CASE OBJECT_KIND
    WHEN 'O' THEN 'Table' --1
    WHEN 'T' THEN 'Table' --1
    WHEN 'V' THEN 'View'  --2
    WHEN 'M' THEN 'Macro' --3
    WHEN 'G' THEN 'Trigger'  --4
    WHEN 'P' THEN 'Stored Procedure'  --5
    WHEN 'I' THEN 'Join Index'  --6
    WHEN 'F' THEN 'Function'  --7
    WHEN 'FK' THEN 'Foreign Key' --0
    ELSE 'ND'
END;
```

And I have the following query using the UDF:

```
SELECT A.DATABASE_ID,
B.TABLENAME AS OBJECT_NAME,
GET_OBJECT_TYPE(B.TABLEKIND) AS OBJECT_TYPE,
MAX(CASE WHEN IDCOLTYPE IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS FLAG_IDENTITY_COLUMN
FROM MIGRATION_TOOL.VW_TERADATA_DATABASE A
INNER JOIN DBC.TABLESV B ON A.DATABASE_NAME = B.DATABASENAME
LEFT JOIN DBC.COLUMNSV C ON B.DATABASENAME = C.DATABASENAME AND B.TABLENAME = C.TABLENAME
WHERE B.TABLENAME NOT LIKE ALL ('BKP%')
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

The query fails with the following error message:

> Executed as Single statement.  Failed [3706 : 42000] Syntax error: Data Type  "TABLEKIND" does not match a Defined Type name. 
>   Elapsed time = 00:00:00.283 
>   STATEMENT 1: Select Statement failed.

I checked the data type of TableKind and it is CHAR(1) so it should be accepted by the UDF which accepts VARCHAR(2). Any idea about the cause the issue?

Comment: Try qualifying the UDF: `MIGRATION_TOOL.GET_OBJECT_TYPE(B.TABLEKIND) AS OBJECT_TYPE`. Btw, you the databasename in `SPECIFIC` doesn't match the database in your REPLACE

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth, the database name was a typo in my question but correct in the db... I tried qualifying the UDF and receive the following error: Executed as Single statement.  Failed [5628 : HY000] Column MIGRATION_TOOL not found in MIGRATION_TOOL.A, DBC.B or DBC.C.

Comment: Your original Select is valid syntax, you get this *does not match a Defined Type name*  when there's an unknown UDF name. The 2nd error indicates that the database `MIGRATION_TOOL` doesn't exist, check for a typo.

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth there was indeed a typo in my code and calling the UDF with the database name solved the "Data Type does not match" issue... Do you want to create an answer with this? I would accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User defined functions must be called with the database name in which the UDF is created.
This worked:

```
SELECT A.DATABASE_ID,
B.TABLENAME AS OBJECT_NAME,
MIGRATION_TOOL.GET_OBJECT_TYPE(B.TABLEKIND) AS OBJECT_TYPE,
MAX(CASE WHEN IDCOLTYPE IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS FLAG_IDENTITY_COLUMN
FROM MIGRATION_TOOL.VW_TERADATA_DATABASE A
INNER JOIN DBC.TABLESV B ON A.DATABASE_NAME = B.DATABASENAME
LEFT JOIN DBC.COLUMNSV C ON B.DATABASENAME = C.DATABASENAME AND B.TABLENAME = C.TABLENAME
WHERE B.TABLENAME NOT LIKE ALL ('BKP%')
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```